# What is the best way to encrypt long user input so that I cannot look in the database and immediately see everyone's writing?

Tags: python, sql, encryption, sqlalchemy

I'm creating a website where users can write about their day in a sort of diary. Right now, if a user decides to write something even remotely personal I can immediately see that just by querying the database for their entry content. I was wondering what the best way would be to encrypt this diary entry I get from the user so it would at least take some more effort from myself to see what people are writing. I am using Flask and SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if its a matter of human readability, you could just base64 encode it - therefore obfuscating it, instead of encrypting it. This is included in the python standard library, here's an example:

https://www.base64encoder.io/python/

If it needs to be encrypted, you could assign the user a private key and encrypt the data with its corresponding public key. This may be overkill, unless you do not want anyone else to be able to read it, even with a lot of effort put into it. Obviously you need to keep those private keys secret to anyone except the user, which would be complicated and you would not be able to assist the users if they lose their keys.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, mainly the purpose is so that I can't just do Entry.query.all() and see exactly what everyone wrote, so base64 encoding should work great!

Comment: thats nice. Just for your information (if anyone asks), base64 is not considered an "encryption", but an "encoding", because anyone can get back the original text without any further information provided.